# variable initialization within an if statement blocks

Tags: c++

Every time I initialize a variable within an *if-statement*'s blocks and its *else*'s blocks, and use it afterward, the compiler spits an error: the variable isn't declared. For example:

```
if (/*Some expression*/)
  int a=5;
else
  int& a=c;

//...

a++; // Variable not declared
```

My compiler would say that *a* is not declared. The main problem about any declaration other than in an *if-statement* is that in one case the variable *a* must be a reference, which must be set when it is initialized. Also, I don't really want to create a new variable unless it is necessary, which it isn't when it could be a reference.

Is there something else I'm doing wrong? Or a way to pass the error? Or some type of variable prototype?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables in C++ have a specific type; `a` cannot be an `int` sometimes, and an `int &` at other times.  So there is no way that your code would ever make sense.  And as you've already found, the "scope" of variables is limited to the block they were declared in.

Without knowing what you're trying to solve, I can't really be any more specific than that.