# Returning a variable value outside if-else block

Tags: c++

I want to convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time.

```
int midHour = 15;
int midHour12 = midHour - 12;
if(midHour <= 12)
{
    midHour12 = midHour;
    string meridiem("AM");
}
else
{
    midHour12 = midHour - 12;
    string meridiem("PM");
}
cout << midHour12 << meridiem;
```

However, I have no idea how to get meridiem to 'escape' from the if else block. It's scope is too small. How can I access the value of meridiem outside the if-else block?

The answer at [variable initialization within an if statement blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776247/variable-initialization-within-an-if-statement-blocks) does not answer the question.

Comment: Just as a side note, I use meridiem to refer to AM and PM because AM is ante meridiem (meaning before noon) and PM is post meridiem (meaning after noon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `meridiem` *outside* the if block. You also need to use `=` to assign to `meridiem` after it's declared:

```
string meridiem;                                                               /*
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                               */

if (midHour <= 12)
{
    midHour12 = midHour;
    meridiem = "AM";                                                           /*
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                           */
}
else
{
    midHour12 -= 12;
    meridiem = "PM";                                                           /*
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                           */
}
```

Otherwise the variable will go out of scope by the ending bracket.

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was that when I declared meridiem outside the if-else block, I used `meridiem("AM")` instead of `meridiem="AM"`.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare `meridiem` first:

```
   int midHour12;
    string meridiem;
    if(midHour <= 12)
    {
        midHour12 = midHour;
        meridiem = "AM";
    }
    else
    {
        midHour12 = midHour - 12;
        meridiem = "PM";
    }
    cout << meridiem;
```

---

Or if You don't need `meridiem` later, just print `midHour12`, and in the if-else print "AM" or "PM"

Comment: I needed meridiem later, so it was necessary to make `string meridiem;`

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `meridiem` before the if-else block because variables declared inside the *{...}* can be only seen from inside the block.

```
string meridiem;

int midHour = 15;
int midHour12 = midHour - 12;
if(midHour <= 12)
{
    midHour12 = midHour;
    meridiem = "AM";
}
else
{
    midHour12 = midHour - 12;
    meridiem = "PM";
}
cout << midHour12 << meridiem;
```

Answer (score 2):

c++11 lambda answer just for fun:

```
#include <string>

 auto currentTime = [](int midHour)
 {
    return (midHour <= 12) ? std::to_string(midHour) + "AM" : std::to_string(midHour - 12) + "PM";
 }

 cout << currentTime(15);
```

Comment: I would upvote but I reached my daily limit. Consider this a moral +1